# Determinant of $det(E+\beta u u^TJ)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $J \in Mat_{2n \times 2x}(\mathbb{R})$ - Skew-symmetric matrix( $A^T = -A$), $\beta \in \mathbb{R}+$, $u \in \mathbb{R}_{2n}$ - nonzero vector
>
> I need to find $det(I+\beta u u^TJ)$

For case $2 \times 2$ its easy:

$$B=u u^T J = \left ( \begin{matrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \end{matrix} \right ) \left ( \begin{matrix} u_1  u_2 \end{matrix} \right ) 
\left ( \begin{matrix} 0 & j\\ -j & 0\end{matrix} \right )$$
$$ B =  \left ( \begin{matrix} -u_1 u_2 j & u_1^2j\\ -u_2^2j & u_1 u_2 j \end{matrix} \right )$$

$$det(I+\beta B) = 1 $$

---

I tried with large dimensions - in all cases answer is 1,
 but i have no idea how to prove it in general case. Any hint will be appriciated

Comment: $E$ it's identity matrix (it's synonim to $I$). J can't contains zeroes on diagonal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Sylvester determinant theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_identity) (or the  [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma)). It states that
$$\det(I+ \beta u u^T J)  =\det(1+ \beta u^TJ u)  .$$

Now we have that $u^TJ u$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix and thus
$$\det(I+ \beta u u^T J)  =\det(1+ \beta u^TJ u)
=  1+ \beta u^TJ u.$$

Note that so far, we have not used the fact that $J$ is antisymmetric at all.

With $J$ antisymmetric, we have additionally
$$ u^T J u= -u^T J^T u = - (u^T J u)^T = - u^T J u$$
such that $u^T J u=0$ and thus
$$\det(I+\beta uu^T J)= 1.$$

Comment: It's awesome! Thanks. Never knows when there is a theorem that makes task easier